# Why does a SELECT (JOIN on regex) gets 30x slower with +1 row (query plan stays the same)? Lack of memory?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, explain, postgresql-performance

Here is my query, it takes **2.7 sec**:

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.id FROM sample t1
INNER JOIN (select * from regex_set limit 33) t2 ON t1.data ~* t2.regex;
```

The associated `EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,BUFFERS)` output:

```
Nested Loop (cost=0.00..1108.30 rows=356 width=8) (actual time=56.130..2740.906 rows=33 loops=1)
 Join Filter: (t1.data ~* regex_set.regex)
 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 65967
 Buffers: local hit=18
 -> Seq Scan on sample t1 (cost=0.00..38.59 rows=2159 width=36) (actual time=0.014..1.534 rows=2000 loops=1)
    Buffers: local hit=17
 -> Materialize (cost=0.00..1.08 rows=33 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.004 rows=33 loops=2000)
    Buffers: local hit=1
    -> Limit (cost=0.00..0.59 rows=33 width=36) (actual time=0.005..0.014 rows=33 loops=1)
       Buffers: local hit=1
       -> Seq Scan on regex_set (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.004..0.008 rows=33 loops=1)
          Buffers: local hit=1
Planning time: 0.129 ms
Execution time: 2740.952 ms
```

The same query with limit set to 32 takes only **0.25 sec** with same plan (there is nothing special with row 33: tested `limit 32 offset 1`, had the same result as below):

```
Nested Loop (cost=0.00..1075.88 rows=345 width=8) (actual time=5.871..255.315 rows=32 loops=1)
 Join Filter: (t1.data ~* regex_set.regex)
 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 63968
 Buffers: local hit=18
 -> Seq Scan on sample t1 (cost=0.00..38.59 rows=2159 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.498 rows=2000 loops=1)
    Buffers: local hit=17
 -> Materialize (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=32 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.002 rows=32 loops=2000)
    Buffers: local hit=1
    -> Limit (cost=0.00..0.57 rows=32 width=36) (actual time=0.003..0.013 rows=32 loops=1)
       Buffers: local hit=1
       -> Seq Scan on regex_set (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=32 loops=1)
          Buffers: local hit=1
Planning time: 0.109 ms
Execution time: 255.374 ms
```

Here is the initialisation script I used for these tests.

```
DO $$
  DECLARE s_length INT=2000;
  DECLARE r_length INT=50;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE sample AS
      SELECT generate_series(1, s_length) id, md5(random() :: text) AS data;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS regex_set;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE regex_set AS
      SELECT g.id, s.data regex
      FROM generate_series(1, r_length) g (id),
           sample s
      WHERE s.id = round(g.id * s_length / r_length);
END $$;
```

With my real data, I had a delay at **exactly the same `33 limit`** (the time difference was 1 to 30).

I'm running Postgres 10 on Docker container (2 cpu / 2GB RAM) with following (arbitrary) edits to default postgres.conf (didn't have much effect):

```
shared_buffers = 512MB
temp_buffers = 32MB
work_mem = 16MB (also set to 64MB, had no effect)
```

Equivalent query is a lot faster on default MySQL 5.8 container.

Is there any Postgres master that could explain what is happening?

Comment: You say it's nothing special but can you show us the data in those regexes (and especially the one in row 33)?

Comment: Does increasing `work_mem` help? If yes, it would prove that it's a memory thing

Comment: I'm stumped.  Any chance you can anonymize the data enough to share a full reproduction case?  Or, can you install debug symbols and use `perf` to profile what the slow case is spending its time doing?  Or use `top` to see if it is CPU bound versus something else (IO due to swapping, for example)?

Comment: You could try to rewrite the derived table to a CTE as they are optimized in a different way, e.g.: `with a2 as (select regex from t2 LIMIT 33) SELECT t1.id FROM t1 join a2 ON t1.descr ~* a2.regex;` But it would be interesting to find out what the root cause is. Maybe you should post that on the [performance mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) the devs might have more ideas on how debug this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, as you said, I want to understand what is happening, otherwise the best alternative for my need is, I think, to use a function... Ok, I'll probably try the mailing list if I don't have any answer here.

@jjanes, I'm not familiar with `debug symbols` and `perf`, I will look into it when I have time. Top indicates: swap not used, cpu at 100%. Luckily, I could reproduce the problem with generic data, and surprisingly I get the delay at the same `limit 33`. Updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the full example.  With that and a little help from "perf" and "gdb", I traced the problem down to this:

```
src/backend/utils/adt/regexp.c:#define MAX_CACHED_RES   32
```

Once you are trying to hold 33 regexps in working memory and accessing them in a predictable cycle, each one pushes out of the cache the one that will be needed next, and so every regexp is recompiled every time it is needed.  This recompilation is slow.

I don't know why 32 was chosen for that value, but clearly the cache can't be made unlimited in size.  Maybe it would be nice of this were user-settable rather than compiled in.

With this knowledge, it is easy to tweak the query to change the order of the join execution so that one regexp is tested to completion before moving on to the next one:

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.id FROM sample t1
right JOIN (select * from regex_set limit 33) t2 ON t1.data ~* t2.regex
```

However, if there are regexp in t2 which match no rows in t1, then this query will start returning null-extended results for those rows, which is a change in behavior from your existing query.  And if you try to add a simple WHERE clause to filter out those extra rows, then the planner will see through your trick and go back to using the slow join order.  You could try to use a non-transparent equivalent to filter them out:

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.id FROM sample t1
right JOIN (select * from regex_set limit 33) t2 ON t1.data ~* t2.regex 
where coalesce(t1.id,-5) != -5
```

(assuming real t1.id are always positive)

But perhaps the best solution to this problem is to build a speciality index which supports regexp queries:

```
create extension pg_trgm ;
create index on sample using gin (data gin_trgm_ops);
```

The prospect of using that index will inherently require the faster join order to be used, and the actual use of the index will make the query faster as well.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! I will try c debugging next time :)